# giving grep output to rm

Tags: bash, grep, rm

I'm trying to pipe `grep` output to `rm`, but it outputs useless stuff. Is any switch required for `rm`? Or can `rm` can be provided a regexp directly?

```
ls | grep '^\[Daruchini'| rm
```

rm: missing operand
Try `rm --help' for more information.

Comment: Always copy-paste error messages. (I've inserted the actual error message for the benefit of future readers. But I could only do this because there's only one possible error message in this case. Most of the time, it's vital to have the **exact** error message to understand the problem. So always copy-paste all error messages in full.)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You need to use `xargs` to turn standard input into arguments for `rm`.

```
$ ls | grep '^Dar' | xargs rm
```

(Beware of special characters in filenames; with GNU grep, you might prefer

```
$ ls | grep -Z '^Dar' | xargs -0 rm
```

)

Also, while the shell doesn't use regexps, that's a simple pattern:

```
$ rm Dar*
```

(meanwhile, I think I need more sleep.)

Comment: Assuming the asker didn't make a mistake when (s)he posted the question, (s)he's after `rm Dar*`, not `rm !(Dar*)`.

Comment: ...right, yes, I was stuck in `zsh` `^` mode (similar to the `basg` `!` thing).

Comment: +1 Great answer, I had to add `| tr "\n" "\0"` before the `xargs` bit.  Seen in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307299/linux-why-cant-i-pipe-find-result-to-rm

Answer (score 8):

[Do not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Here, it's very simple to get the shell to filter the files you want. Note that it's the shell that's expanding the pattern `Dar*`, not the `rm` command. The pattern expansion performed by the shell is called [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29).

```
rm Dar*
```

In more complex cases, look up the `find` command.

Comment: Late addition, but to add on to this answer, including the `-i` option will ask you to confirm before removing as a sanity check.

Answer (score 5):

For passing output as an argument, I tend to use a while loop since I'm not familiar with xargs.

```
ls | grep '^Dar' | while read line; do rm "$line";done;
```

Comment: this is the only one that worked in my case.

Comment: Yes, this is the only one actually working properly.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to delimit the output of `grep` by newlines rather than whitespace, you can specify that to `xargs` via the `-d` option.

```
$ ls | grep '^Dar' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

(as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142776/xargs-split-at-newlines-not-spaces) question)

Answer (score 2):

On Catalina 10.15.3, with zsh, the way I found to deal with newlines and white spaces was:

```
 sudo find / | grep -i 'yourString' | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n1 rm -r
```

In other words, by translating new lines with no space (tr \n to \0) before removing it with "rm -0".

Also, I always use 'find'+'grep -i' because 'find -iname' sometimes doesn't output anything.

One last note: it finds and remove files and folders that matches 'yourString'.
For files only, specify "find -type f", and then the option "-r" for rm is useless.

Answer (score 0):

The best command for me is:

```
find ./Daruchini* -exec rm {}\;
```